# Prometheus - PromQL - filter by dict attribute

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to get memory usage by K8S PODs in particular states only:

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"}})
```

but am getting an error: "parse error: unexpected left brace '{'"

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Do u have metrics like kube_pod_status_phase? 

In this case, u can't pass metric as lable

Comment: Does that mean I can get memory usage and kube_pod_status_phase per POD and time (/api/v1/query_range) and process it externally?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate sum memory usage  in kube_pod_status_phase:

`sum(container_memory_usage_bytes) by (kube_pod_status_phase)`

or if you want to sum all memory usage :

`sum(container_memory_usage_bytes)`